# An Election Problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, markov-chains, markov-process, discrete-calculus

Consider a country of $N$ people, where a president is elected every year. He is picked at random and his mandate can be renewed any number of times, but once he steps off he can't be re-elected.

Call $p_t(n)$ the probability that at time $t$ there are $n$ viable candidates, besides the current president. We have

$$p_{t+1}(n) = \frac{n+1}{n+2} p_t(n+1) + \frac{1}{n+1} p_t(n)$$

with the initial condition $p_0(n)=\delta_{nN-1}$.

How would you tackle such a recurrence equation?

In terms of the generating functional $F_z(n) = \sum_{t\geq 0} P_t(n) z^t$, I can write

$$\frac{n+1}{n+2} F_z(n+1) = \left(\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) F_z(n) - \frac{\delta_{n N-1}}{z}$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed then.

Comment: Where does this recurrence stem from?

Comment: I'm adding it into my question, it will make it clearer.

Comment: @Dominik, at time $t+1$ the probability of having $n$ viable candidates comes from $n+1$ at time $t$ as long as the current president is not re-elected, or the probability that there were $n$ at time $t$ and he is re-elected. although i think the first term should be $(n+1)/(n+2)$?

Comment: you should also relabel so that $p_0(n) = \delta_{n, N-1},$ otherwise the relation is incorrect

Comment: Thank you cats! I fixed those mistakes in the question. The generating functional equation looks uglier now, though...